Custom Exception handling in sprint boot
I have written the below Custom Error Handler in SPRING BOOT but in the Error response only time is coming. But I can see the values in debug mode not sure why the values are not coming in the response. Can anyone help me to fix the issue. Appreciate any help as it blocked my development.
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomControllerAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler(CustomDataNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleCustomDataNotFoundExceptions(
            Exception e
    ) {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND; // 404

        // converting the stack trace to String
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
        e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
        String stackTrace = stringWriter.toString();

      //  ErrorResponse response = new ErrorResponse();

        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(
                new ErrorResponse(
                        status,
                        e.getMessage()

                ),
                status
        );
    } 

POJO Class:


public class ErrorResponse {
    // customizing timestamp serialization format
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    private Date timestamp;

    private int code;

    private String status;

    private String message;

    private String stackTrace;

    private Object data;



    public ErrorResponse(
            HttpStatus httpStatus,
            String message
    ) {
       // this();

        this.code = httpStatus.value();
        this.status = httpStatus.name();
        this.message = message;
        timestamp = new Date();
    }


}

Response :

{
    "timestamp": "18-04-2024 11:15:41"
}

